# Footnote numbering breaks when caption of a figure on a page has footnote

Tags: memoir

I noted that the footnote numbering is missing the footnotes that appear in a minipage. The footnote on the first page is displayed correctly as in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtXcr.png), the footnote on the figure page [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeA7R.png) is shown as letter instead of number. The footnote after the figure page do not consider the footers on the figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBXum.png). How can I make the footnote number contiguous and use the same style throughout?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext

some text
\section{Outline}
\blindtext

some text. some text\footnote{Foot note text 1}. More text

\begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{red.png}
        \caption[A caption 1]{A caption 1}
        \label{fig:figure1}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{green.png}          
        \caption[A caption 2]{A caption 2\footnote{reproduced from ... }.}
        \label{fig:figure2}        
   \end{minipage}     
    \end{figure}
\FloatBarrier

\section{Approach} \label{documentclasses}
\blindtext

some text

\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two  
\item three
\item four 
\end{itemize}
some text\footnote{Foot note text 3}. some text\footnote{Foot note text 4}. More text \footnote{Foot note text 5}. More text
\end{document}
```

[image: Page two footnote]
[image: Page three footnoote]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank Mittelbach and Michael Goosens *The Latex Companion Second Edition*, Adison Wesley, 2004 give an example in section 3.2.1 *Using standard footnotes* as

```
\noindent\ldots{} main text \ldots
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
  Footnotes in a minipage are numbered using
  lowecase letter.\footnote{Inside minipage}
  \par This text references a footnote at the
  bottom of the the page.\footnotemark{}
  And another\footnote{Inside again} note.
\end{minipage}\footnotetext{At bottom of page}
\end{center}
\ldots{} main text \ldots
```

which will give two footnotes (a Inside minipage  and b Inside again) at the bottom of the minipage and one (1 At bottom of page) at the bottom of the page.

Basically LaTeX uses a different numbering scheme and placement for footnotes in a minipage, but as above you can get one put at the bottom of the page following the regular numbering scheme.

Without doing a lot of recoding of basic LaTeX you have a choice of footnotes within minipages with their own numbering scheme (lower case letters) or footnotes at the bottom of the page with their own numbering scheme (numbers).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I have updated the caption footnote as indicated and the footnote numbering is correct. However, the foot note text is not displayed anywhere in the document. I tried to change the figure placement options and remove the floatbarrier with no success.

Comment: @kpenza You say what you have done but if anyone else tries to do that will they reproduce your code? Could be a problem with your description or with someone else's interpretation. We need to see exactly what you have done, probably best by you asking a new question.